# Water Solution keep getting error message "did not find 12\n"

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

   printf("How many minutes do you shower for?\n");
   int minutes = get_int();
   int bottles = minutes * (192/16);
   printf("Minutes: %i\n",minutes);
   printf("Bottles: %i\n",bottles);
   printf("%i minute equals %i bottles.\n", minutes, bottles);

do {
   minutes = get_int();
}
while (minutes < 0);
}
```

This may be a simple problem, but I am very stuck right now and would appreciate the help!

When I use check50 to check the code this message keeps popping up:

```
:) water.c exists.
:) water.c compiles.
:) 1 minute equals 12 bottles.
:) 2 minute equals 24 bottles.
:( 5 minute equals 60 bottles.
    timed out while waiting for program to exit
:( 10 minute equals 120 bottles.
    timed out while waiting for program to exit
:) rejects "foo" minutes
:) rejects "" minutes
:) rejects "123abc" minutes
```

Comment: Doesn't the test bench simply expect a newline after the number?

Comment: It apparently doesn't like your third `printf´ (but doesn't complain about the other two). What if you just remove the third one?

Comment: @BoPersson I tried to do that, still getting the same error message unfortunately.

Comment: Try swapping minutes for bottles in that last printf. It will be wrong, but if cs50 likes it, then you've found a bug in cs50.

Comment: The only place I found "did not find" in check50.py was in a TIMEOUT exception handler?  Your C code looks fine to me, check50 is suspect.

Comment: There is no confirmation because I do not know the required specifications, but is not it just a different output format?

Comment: @jwdonahue I changed the code a bit. A new error message is now popping up. It executes, but stops half way.

Comment: You have an infinite do..while loop.